# How to do MVVM using KnockoutJs in Chrome Packaged App? it doesntt allow inline JS in html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Now I'm using KnockoutJs, and I want to develop Chrome Packeaged App.
I am wondering how to bind data MVVM. Because at http://developer.chrome.com said cannot use inline javascript in html. JS must be separated file.

So how can i write this MVVM works for click? and or even more with knockout?

```
<span data-bind="text : $data.name, click : $root.load> </span>
<span data-bind="text:shoppingCart().somethingChange()"></span>
```

Comment: You can indeed use knockout.js. The top rated answer isn't the ultimate solution. I'll write how I fixed the problem for my extension.

Comment: @AlexStack Incorrect (your solution works for extensions, but not apps)

Comment: One option is my plugin: https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding  –  Some folks have reported success with Chrome packaged apps using it.

Answer (score 5):

### Quick Version

You can't really use it unless you sandbox the page and drop certain features.

---

### Long Version

The Chrome Packaged Apps require that the code and any libraries used be [CSP compliant](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html). In other words, it is impossible to use `eval()`, `new Function()`, any `<script></script>` HTML tag and some other stuff.

Knockout uses a some of these for the bindings and for the templates. Therefore, you cannot use Knockout has is for Chrome Packaged Apps.

Furthermore, I've found some info pointing out that Knockout's developers are not aiming at making it CSP compliant. You can find this on their [Git repo](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/903).

There are some very similar problems with Chrome Extensions. What I've read on the subject involved sandboxing an iframe... After a bit more [digging](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html#sandboxing), sandboxing will cause the page to be unable to use certain features.

The only alternative is to use a custom binding provider for Knockout. Yet, I find it more compelling to use another MV* library at that point.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this

> You can't really use it unless you sandbox the page and drop certain
>   features.

No longer holds.

As long as you add:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
```

To the root level of manifest.json.

I just tried it with a simple:
`<h1 data-bind="text: version().length"></h1>`

in a `default_popup` page and found no problems with it, at least for Chrome in its: 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) version

Comment: Downvote: the question is about Chrome Apps. Chrome Apps cannot override CSP like extensions do.

Comment: To help those in need, this answer does work for chrome extensions. Don't know about chrome apps though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to bind text, not an action (like 'click'), so the easiest would be to add a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to your model, calculate the value you need in its function, and bind it to the span.

Answer (score -2):

Knockout's data binding does not use inline javascript in the html, the HTML data-bind attribute merely defines a string expression which may contain javascript-like expressions which knockout will parse and execute from it's external script file. You shouldn't run into any problems with knockout MVVM's data-binding

Comment: False.. its not CSP compliant. :(